# OAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal() returns client_id instead of username

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure version 2.1.6.RELEASE to secure a resource server and am trying to get the username that is listed in my jwt. The payload of my jwt contains the client_id and username. When I try to get the Principal from the `OAuth2Authentication` object, it returns the `client_id` instead of the username.

For example, if the jwt payload contains:

```
client_id":"2v3r098kgipu053lph0cb9nfjb","username":"7e953975-0df2-49ff-9b23-cae0864384b7"
```

And my code is:

```java
@GetMapping("/whoami")
public String whoami(@CurrentSecurityContext OAuth2Authentication auth) {
    logger.debug("auth.name: {}", auth.getName() );
    logger.debug("auth.principal: {}", auth.getPrincipal());
    OAuth2Request req = auth.getOAuth2Request();
    logger.debug("req.clientid: {}", req.getClientId() );
    return "success";
}
```

I see the following in the log:

```
auth.name: 2v3r098kgipu053lph0cb9nfjb  
auth.principal: 2v3r098kgipu053lph0cb9nfjb  
req.clientid: 2v3r098kgipu053lph0cb9nfjb
```

What do I need to do to get the username from the jwt?

Comment: Just tried it, it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.

This is the `OAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal()` method:

```java
public Object getPrincipal() {
        return this.userAuthentication == null ? this.storedRequest.getClientId() : this.userAuthentication
                .getPrincipal();
    }
```

`auth.getUserAuthentication()` returns null so this explains the results I'm seeing.

The reason why `this.userAuthentication` is null is because the `DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter.extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map)` method tries to set the principal to `map.get(USERNAME)` where the map is the jwt and `USERNAME = "user_name"` instead of `"username"`.

This question had a similar issue: [Override UserAuthenticationConverter for JWT OAuth Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845108/override-userauthenticationconverter-for-jwt-oauth-tokens). I was able to use their solution and alter it for my needs. I also decided to use the `sub` from the jwt instead of `username`.